# On a derivative of the Poynting vector's derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

I'm studying the Poynting theorem (the mathematical proof). It starts considering the energy held by the electromagnetic field inside a surface $S$, which is:

$$
U_{em} = \int_{\tau}\frac{1}{2}(\vec{E}\cdot\vec{D})\ \mathrm{d}\tau + \int_{\tau}\frac{1}{2}(\vec{H}\cdot\vec{B})\ \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

where d$\tau$ is the infinitesimal volume inside $S$. Now the energy is derived in time, giving the expression:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}U_{em}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_{\tau}\vec{E}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{D}}{\mathrm{d}t} + \vec{H}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{B}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

So here's what I'm not understanding: why, mathematically speaking
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{1}{2}(\vec{E}\cdot\vec{D}) = \vec{E}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{D}}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$

I know is about differential properties of the fields, but I really can't figure out why, also because the derivation a time derivative and I cnnot understand if the fields depend on time this way $\vec{E}\equiv\vec{E}(x,y, z, t)$ (just the magnitude) or this way $\vec{E}\equiv\vec{E}(x(t), y(t), z(t))$...

Thanks for helping, even on a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the product rule. First, what is $\mathbf{D}$? $\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{x}, t) = \epsilon(\mathbf{x}, t)\, \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}, t)$, right? Thus:
\begin{array}
\ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t} \left(\mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{E}\right) & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t} \left(\epsilon \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{E}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left[\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{E}\frac{\operatorname{d}\epsilon }{\operatorname{d}t} + 2\epsilon \mathbf{E} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbf{E}}{\operatorname{d}t} \right].
\end{array}
If $\epsilon$ is constant in time, then the first term vanishes. The $\epsilon$ in the second term can then be brought inside the derivative to change the $\mathbf{E}$ back into a $\mathbf{D}$, giving the desired result.